# How can I save the training results in the current working directory of Machine Learning Studio?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Current I am following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-automated-ml-forecast?view=azureml-api-2 to use the AutoML pipeline of Machine Learning Studio to collect some training results.

How can I save the training results in the current working directory of Machine Learning Studio, so that I do not have to repeat running same trainings all the time to get the training results?

I appreciate any assistance and comments.
Best Regards,

Comment: Can you provide more details on the issue such as error details, code used and your setup?

Comment: Unfortunately the notebook that I originally followed was removed. A similar workflow is here: https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/blob/main/sdk/python/jobs/automl-standalone-jobs/automl-forecasting-github-dau/auto-ml-forecasting-github-dau.ipynb

There were no error details. My question is, I would like to know how the training results can be saved in the current working directory after running the codes of Section 5.1 Download the best model.

Comment: What do you mean by training results.Is it model or artifacts? If so, you use the code in section 5.1 in the link you given.

Comment: According to the link you shared the artifacts are downloading  in "./artifact_downloads/outputs". Do you want the output in current directory?

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced the setup using the provided link:
By default, the training output is saved in `"./artifact_downloads"` as per the shared notebook.

[image: Default Output]

To save the training artifacts in current directory you can use `os.getcwd()`.
With this I'm able save the artifacts in current directory.

[image: Modified Output]

Also, by default the `artifacts_path` is "**outputs**".
If you want to have particular file from artifacts, you can modify the path to specific file that needed to be saved in current directory.

Comment: What I was looking for is the training result not directly from best_run, but additional results say from pandas dataframe. At the end I saved the result as Data Assets. The solution is good. Thanks @RishabhM for showing the code and the output.